# Constexpr function is not constexpr when template is used

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

The following code compiles fine:

```
struct A {
    int i;
    constexpr A() : i(1) { }
    constexpr A(const A& that) : i(1) { }
};
constexpr auto func() {
    std::array<A, 3> result = {};
    return result;
}
```

However, if we add a template type parameter `T` to `A`,

```
template<typename T> struct A {
    int i;
    constexpr A() : i(1) { }
    constexpr A(const A<T>& that) : i(1) { }
};
constexpr auto func() {
    std::array<A<int>, 3> result = {};
    return result;
}
```

the compiler errors "*constexpr function 'func' cannot result in a constant expression*".

How is this possible?

Comment: Which compiler? On [Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/946ae65e81ebcf18), it compiles fine.

Comment: Compiler: Microsoft visual C++ 14.16.27023

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, MSVC had (or still has) some problems with the implementation of C++14/17 features, and that obviously also applies to `constexpr`. With Visual Studio 2017 15.9, however, the following slight modification works for me (whereas the version in the OP also gives an error):

```
template<typename T> struct A {
    int i;
    constexpr A() : i(1) { }
    constexpr A(const A<T>& that) : i(1) { }
};
constexpr auto func() {
    return std::array<A<int>, 3>{};
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this a bug in the MSVC compiler?

Comment: Yes, it's a bug. It's probably something related to the copy constructor or to copy(-list) initialization.